# Firebase reference object cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, firebase

I just start building my Android app by following this docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html

After setting up libraries and permission, I start typing the very few lines of code. And immediately I got a list of compile errors as shown below:

[image]

I then tried typing "dataRef." and Ctr+Space, there was no Default Proposals but a a red message saying "dataRef can not be resolved to a type". dataRef is the reference to firebase database (just like the one in the docs's snippet)

[image]

So what was wrong?

Ps: I also tried cleaning the project.
I believe that my Firebase library is the latest, as its name is "firebase-client-jvm-LATEST" and I just downloaded it today.
I din't add any xml or build anything yet.
Below is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.biz.nah;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create a reference to database
        String url = "https://nah.firebaseio.com";
        Firebase dataRef = new Firebase(url);

        dataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                 // Do some stuff once
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled() {
                 System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
             }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct, although the screenshot of your eclipse window prove otherwise.

The errors sound like eclipse isn't parsing your code correctly.

Another clue to this, is in the outline view `url` and `dataref` are shown as `MainActivity`'s fields rather than function variables, like you posted in your code.

Try:

- Close and open Eclipse
- Project -> Clean

Comment: Hi yah, I also realize the difference b/t my code and the screenshot. But that was because later I tried putting my code into the onCreate method. I have done Clean many times before and it dint work. I then shutdown, went to sleep, woke up several hours later, open eclipse again, same problem, but now, when I start typing (not copy-paste the snippet), it works. The chunk of coppied code, even though similar, remains the same errors, so I deleted it.