# Firebase cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, firebase

I'm trying to follow the tutorial found here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

I want to set up an Android app that uses the Firebase database, because it seems pretty easy and difficult to break. But I'm stuck at the part of the tutorial where you have to add the line

```
Firebase f = new Firebase("https://android.firebaseio-demo.com");
```

to MainActivity.java. I get a compilation error:

"Firebase cannot be resolved to a type".

I've already downloaded the latest version of the firebase client jar, v 1.0.18, and I added it to my build path. Any ideas how to resolve? I tried this link, but the solution didn't work for me:

[Firebase reference object cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21212921/firebase-reference-object-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

I've also attached a screenshot of my eclipse window of the bug.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEXTE.png

EDIT: I forgot to import the actual package.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you `import com.firebase.client.Firebase`?

Comment: Aha! Fixed it. Thanks. Can't believe I forgot that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `import com.firebase.client.Firebase`